# Spring boot batch Spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

i am using Spring boot + Spring Batch + JPA + Mysql. below are the follow i am following:

1. spring boot application

```

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.xxx.xxxx.config, com.xxx.xxx.rest, com.xxx.xxx.domain, com.xxx.xxx.dataservice, com.xxx.xxx.batchconfiguration, com.xxx.xxx.steps")
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    @EnableConfigurationProperties(Properties.class)
    @EnableEncryptableProperties
    public class SampleApplication
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(SampleApplication.class, args);
        }


    }
```

```

2. Created @Entity classes based on table structure
3. created reposity interface like below

```

```
@Component
public interface ExampleRepository extends JpaRepository<tableClass, Long> {
   Page<tableClass> findTop10ByStatus(tableClassStatus status,
            Pageable pageable);
}
```

```

4. Batch configuration:

```

```
@Configuration
    @EnableScheduling
    public class BatchScheduler {

        @Bean
        public ResourcelessTransactionManager transactionManager() {
            return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
        }

        @Bean
        public JobExplorer jobExplorer() throws Exception {
            MapJobExplorerFactoryBean jobExplorerFactory = new MapJobExplorerFactoryBean(
                    mapJobRepositoryFactory());
            jobExplorerFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
            return jobExplorerFactory.getObject();
        }

        @Bean
        public MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean mapJobRepositoryFactory() throws Exception {
            MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean();
            factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager());
            return factory;
        }

        @Bean
        public JobRepository jobRepository() throws Exception {
            return mapJobRepositoryFactory().getObject();
        }

        @Bean
        public JobLauncher jobLauncher() throws Exception {
            SimpleJobLauncher simpleJobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
            simpleJobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository());
            return simpleJobLauncher;
        }

    }
```

```

5. batch configuration

```

```
@Configuration
    @EnableBatchProcessing
    @Import({ BatchScheduler.class })
    public class BatchConfiguration2 {

        @Autowired
        public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

        @Autowired
        public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

        @Autowired
        private SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher;

        @Autowired
        public ExampleRepository exampleRepository ;

        @Scheduled(cron = "0/5 * * * * ?")
        public void perform() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Job Started at :" + new Date());

            JobParameters param = new JobParametersBuilder()
                    .addString("JobID", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())).toJobParameters();

            JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job(), param);

            System.out.println("Job finished with status :" + execution.getStatus());

        }

        @Bean
        public RepositoryMetadata repositoryMetadata() {
            return new DefaultRepositoryMetadata(ExampleRepository.class);
        }

        @Bean
        public RepositoryItemReader<tableClass> reader() {
            RepositoryItemReader<tableClass> fullfillment = new RepositoryItemReader<tableClass>();
            fullfillment.setRepository(ExampleRepository);
            fullfillment.setMethodName("findTop10ByStatus");
            List<tableClassStatus> list = new ArrayList<tableClassStatus>();
            list.add(tableClassStatus.FULFILLMENT_READY);
            fullfillment.setArguments(list);
            HashMap<String, Sort.Direction> sorts = new HashMap<>();
            sorts.put("id", Direction.DESC);
            fullfillment.setSort(sorts);
            return fullfillment;
        }

        /* @Bean
        public RepositoryItemWriter<tableClass> writer() {
            System.out.println("BatchConfiguration.writer()");
            RepositoryItemWriter<tableClass> itemWriter = new RepositoryItemWriter<tableClass>();
            itemWriter.setRepository(ExampleRepository);
            itemWriter.setMethodName("save");
            return itemWriter;
        }*/

        @Bean
        public RepositoryItemWriter<tableClass> writer() {
            System.out.println("BatchConfiguration.writer()");
            DefaultCrudMethods defaultCrudMethods = new DefaultCrudMethods(repositoryMetadata());
            RepositoryItemWriter<tableClass> itemWriter = new RepositoryItemWriter<tableClass>();
            itemWriter.setRepository(ExampleRepository);
            itemWriter.setMethodName(defaultCrudMethods.getSaveMethod().getName());
            return itemWriter;
        }

        @Bean
        public Step step1() throws Exception {
            return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                    .<tableClass, tableClass> chunk(1).reader(reader())
                    .processor(new QuoteOfferFullfillmentSubmitionProcessor()).writer(writer()).build();
        }


        @Bean
        public Job job() throws Exception {

            return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("job").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).start(step1())
                    .listener(new JobCompletionListener()).build();

        }

    }
```

```

6. QuoteOfferFullfillmentSubmitionProcessor.java

```

```
public class QuoteOfferFullfillmentSubmitionProcessor implements ItemProcessor<QuoteOfferFulfillment, QuoteOfferFulfillment> {

        @Override
        public tableClass process(tableClass item) throws Exception {

            System.out.println("Processor.process() ==> ID " + item.getId());
            System.out.println("Processor.process() ==> " + item.getLenderName());
            System.out.println(
                    "QuoteOfferFullfillmentSubmitionProcessor.process() ==> source" + item.getStatus());
            item.setStatus(QuoteOfferFulfillmentStatus.PROCESSING);
            return item;
        }

    }
```

```

7. JobCompletionListener.java

```

```
public class JobCompletionListener extends JobExecutionListenerSupport {
            @Override
            public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
                if (jobExecution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.COMPLETED) {
                    System.out.println("BATCH JOB COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY");
                }
            }

        }
```

```

after all configuration, running the application every 5 sec the job is running fine, getting values and printing in process class, after that coming to writer class and printing all the values with out Errors.

**the problem is: its not updating the values in the Database in write method.**

**with out BatchScheduler, scheduler and job launcher  (commit the code) restarting the spring boot its all updating the values in database.**

Can you guys suggest me what wrong i am doing.

Comment: No need to use DefaultCurdMethods you can directly use like below.
reader.setMethodName("save");
Question : Is debug point coming to writer bean at all?

Comment: Yes, that’s what I mentioned. All the Sysouts are printing fine, but it’s not persisting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolve the issue. in the batch configuration if i use

```

```
@Bean
    public ResourcelessTransactionManager resourcelessTransactionManager() {
        return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public JobRepository jobRepository() throws Exception {
        return new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(resourcelessTransactionManager()).getObject();
    }
```

```

it started working.

```
Thanks,
Bala.
```